# programmatically retrieve Header component height - React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, native-base

Using NativeBase, I added a Header component. Now, I want to programmatically retrieve the height of the header. How can I do this. The code for adding the Header is given below:

I tried using `Dimensions.get('window')` but it gives me the height of the entire view.

The code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react-native';
import {Container, Header, Button, Title, Icon} from 'native-base';
​
export default class ThemeHeaderExample extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
                <Header>
                    <Button transparent />

                    <Title>Header</Title>

                </Header>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, NativeBase.Header does not expose Height.

I faced the same problem and I dove into the code, I realized Height is harcoded in this way:

```
toolbarHeight: platform === "ios" ? 64 : 56
```

Take a look [here](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/blob/master/src/theme/variables/platform.js) at line **155**. You will end up there following [Header Component](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/blob/master/src/theme/components/Header.js) at line **300**.

Even though this might work, It does not seem to be something we might want to do, or at least, that fixed solution seems to be ugly.

So, what I did was to create my own Header, which is pretty straight forward and easy since it is just a wrapper, and used "refs measure" function that allows us to get position and size. You can see an example [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/953).

Basically, It should look like this:

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container} ref="yourComponent">
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.measureYourComponent}>
          <Text>Measure it</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
}

measureYourComponent() {
    this.refs.yourComponent.measure((ox, oy, width, height, px, py) => {
        console.log("ox: " + ox); //Relative position
        console.log("oy: " + oy); //Relative position
        console.log("width: " + width);
        console.log("height: " + height);
        console.log("px: " + px); //Absolute position
        console.log("py: " + py); //Absolute position
      });
}
```

In my case, I needed to react from some parent depending on a child's size, so replace the OnPress handler for a Handler provided by its parent.

In this way, despite you will need some more effort, you will have a solution more flexible and reusable.

Let me know if there is something to clarify.

Answer (score 4):

I solved it by just importing the variable and using it.

`import toolbarHeight from '../../native-base-theme/variables/platform'`

Answer (score 0):

I don't use native base but you should be able to use `onLayout` props:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#onlayout

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and this is how I fixed it.

Give a styling with your desired height(e.g. 20) and paddingTop of 0.

```html
<Header style={{height: 20, paddingTop:0}}>
    <Button transparent />

    <Title>Header</Title>

</Header>
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I was having an issue with `iPhone X` my [native base Header](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#header-def-headref) was adding `padding from the top` when I use  [SafeAreaView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/safeareaview) then I came with the following workaround, It may solve your problem.

I have tested it on **iPhone X, 8 and android.**

```
import {StatusBar, TouchableOpacity, View, SafeAreaView,platform,Dimensions} from "react-native";
const deviceHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
const deviceWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const platformStyle = undefined;

const isIphoneX =
Platform.OS === 'ios' &&
(deviceHeight === 812 ||
deviceWidth === 812 ||
deviceHeight === 896 ||
deviceWidth === 896);

<Header style={{paddingTop: isIphoneX ? -10 : 15,maxHeight:50,minHeight:50}}>
```